# Count number of existing objects

Tags: java, object, methods, constructor

So I'm making a die class that can create and roll a die, return the value and the size.  I'm trying to figure out how to tell the program how many of them have been created so that I can have a response be different based on how many there are.  IE I want the response from printDie to be Die Value: 5 if there is only one die, and Die 1 Value: 5 if there is more than one.

Here's my code so far.

```
package com.catalyse.die;

import java.util.Random;

public class Die
{
    // instance variables 
    private int myDieValue;
    private int myDieSides;
    private Random myRandom;

    // Dice Class Constructors


    public Die()
    {
        this.myDieValue = 1;
        this.myDieSides = 4;
    }


    public Die(int numSides)
    {
        if ((numSides < 4) || (numSides > 100)) {
            System.out.println("Error! You cannot have more than 100 sides or less than four!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            myDieSides = numSides;
        }
    }

    // getter methods

    public int getDieSides()
    {
        return myDieSides;
    }


    public int getDieValue()
    {
        return myDieValue;
    }

    // setter methods

    private void setDieSides(int newNumSides)
    {
        myDieSides = newNumSides;
    }


    public void rollDie()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        int i = (rand.nextInt(myDieSides) + 1);
        myDieValue = i;
    }

public void printDie(int dieNum)
{
    if (dieNum == 1) {
        System.out.println("Die Value: "+myDieValue);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Die "+dieNum+" Value: "+myDieValue);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Note: Java does not have deconstructors, so by using a static field, if one gets deleted the count will not reflect this change.

Comment: The information you gave is pretty good, but I've got to ask you, what exactly do you mean by *one gets deleted*? Since there is no destructor, there is no deletion. I guess you mean to say, garbage collected, probably? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have static field in your class which could be incremented in the constructor always. The reason why is it should be `static` is because, `static` fields are shared by all instances of a class, thus a local copy of the field won't be created for each of the instances you create.

```
private static int counter = 0;
public Die()
{
    counter++;
    // Other stuffs
}
// Have a getter method for the counter so that you can 
// get the count of instances created at any point of time
public static int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}
```

And then you can call the above method in your calling method like this

```
void someMethodInAnotherClass() {
    int instanceCount = Die.getCounter(); // You need to call static method using the Class name
    // other stuffs.
}
```

Comment: Awesome, so same code, new problem. When I try and test the class the Roll die gives me a nullpointerexception.
Die One = new Die();
One.rollDie();
One.getDieValue();
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Though this should be another question, but I'll answer it for you. You have 2 constructors. One takes in a value to set the `myDieSides` and the other doesn't. Try to call the other, which takes in a value. `Die One = new Die(6);`

Comment: In the extended version of the test I have three die, one is new Die(5) and new Die(99), I've tried each one and they all throw the same exception.

Comment: I suggest you post it as a new question, with the full error stack trace and the exact scenario with the problem. It needs to get the attention it deserves. Also, I can't really tell more from the current scenario. That's why, consider creating a new question! :)

Comment: What happens when an object is de-referenced, how can we decrement `counter`?

Answer (score 3):

Use an static member, that is a 'class' variable, not a 'instance' variable:

```
private static int count = 0;
```

In the constructor:

```
public Die()
{
    count++;
    this.myDieValue = 1;
    this.myDieSides = 4;
}
```

And a getter:

```
public static int getCount() {
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a static variable

```
public class Die{
    static int dieCount = 0;

    public Die(){
        dieCount++;
    }
}
```

Every time a `Die` object is created, the count will increase

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Die die1 = new Die();
    Die die2 = new Die();

    int count = Die.dieCount;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See what is my solution for counting objects in my application

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public abstract class ObjectCounter {

    private static Map<String, Long> classNameCount = new TreeMap<String, Long>();

    public ObjectCounter() {
        String key = this.getClass().getName();
        if (classNameCount.containsKey(key)) {
            classNameCount.put(key, classNameCount.get(key) + 1);
        } else {
            classNameCount.put(key, 1L);
        }
    }

    public static <T extends ObjectCounter> long getCount(Class<T> c) {
        String key = c.getName();
        if (classNameCount.containsKey(key)) {
            return classNameCount.get(key);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static long totalObjectsCreated() {
        long totalCount = 0;

        for (long count : classNameCount.values()) {
            totalCount += count;
        }

        return totalCount;
    }

}
```

Now extends ObjectCounter class

See below

```
package com.omt.factory;

public class Article extends ObjectCounter {

}
```

Now all your other classes are extending Article classes

```
package com.omt.factory;

public class Bio extends Article {

}
```

Now here is our main class

```
package com.omt.factory;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... a) {
        Bio b = new Bio();
        Bio b1 = new Bio();
        Bio b2 = new Bio();
        Bio b3 = new Bio();
        Bio b4 = new Bio();
        com.omt.temp.Bio bio = new com.omt.temp.Bio();

        // Total Objects are created
        System.out.println("Total Objects Created By Application :" + ObjectCounter.totalObjectsCreated());
        // Get Number Of Objects created for class.
        System.out.println("[" + com.omt.temp.Bio.class.getName() + "] Objects Created :"
                + ObjectCounter.getCount(com.omt.temp.Bio.class));
        System.out.println("[" + Bio.class.getName() + "] Objects Created :" + ObjectCounter.getCount(Bio.class));
        System.out.println("[" + Maths.class.getName() + "] Objects Created :" + ObjectCounter.getCount(Maths.class));

    }

}
```

[From this article](http://omtlab.com/object-counter-in-java/)